# Rails 5, Passing variable to partial with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new at rails and I'm trying to pass a variable through AJAX to a partial.

First I create a new pedido and then I make an Ajax call to bring some info from the DB. With that Info I need to select a field and save it into the new pedido.

Here is the html for the new pedido page:

```
#new.html.erb
<%= form_for @pedido do |f| %>
    <div id="Cliente">
        <%= render 'cliente', f: f %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Now in the pedido controller I have:

```
#pedido_controller.rb
def new
   @pedido = Pedido.new
end

def get_cliente
 @cliente = User.find(params[:cliente_id])
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render 'get_cliente', layout: false}
 end
end
```

I make the Ajax call:

```
#pedidos.coffee
jQuery ->
    $(document).ready ->
        $("#pedido_id").on "change", ->
            $.ajax
                url: "/pedidos/get_cliente"
                type: "GET"
                data:
                    cliente_id: $('#pedido_id option:selected').val()
```

My JS file:

```
#get_cliente.js.erb
$('#Cliente').html( "<%=j render('cliente', :locals => {:cliente =>     @cliente, :f => f }) %>" );
$('#Cliente').slideDown(350);
```

And finally my partial has this line:

```
#cliente.html.erb
<%= f.collection_select(:id, @cliente.user_sucursals.all, :id, :nombre,  {include_blank: true}, {:class => "form-control"}) %>
```

So I'd like to save the id from my f.collection_select in _clientes to my new @pedido variable, but I don't know how to assign @pedido variable to my f local in _cliente.

If I take out the line in cliente.html.erb everything works, but I need to add that info to my model.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think you should look at the error / stack trace you are getting when you are making the ajax call. That is a way to debug the issue and you will be able to understand your situation.

Comment: Finally I change the AJAX Url to /pedidos/new and then make a respond_to my partial passing @pedidos as locals.